# Determining if number is between two values in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am doing this:

`case N - ?CONSTANT < SomethingElse < N + ?CONSTANT of`

And this line scares the compiler for some reason -- with "syntax error before <".  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot chain comparison operators like that in Erlang. Use `N - ?CONSTANT < SomethingElse andalso SomethingElse < N + ?CONSTANT`:

```
1> {A, B, C} = {1, 3, 5}.
{1,3,5}
2> A < B < C.
* 1: syntax error before: '<'
2> A < B andalso B < C.
true
```